# What is this type of connector called?

Tags: connector, terminology

I frequently see it as the balance port connector on Lithium Polymer batteries, where it comes in 3-wire to 7-wire variants.  What is its official designation?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [XH connector](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=277) from J.S.T. Manufacturing.

[image: XH wire-to-board connection]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's a JST connector - look the name up!